# Change clickable property on dropzone dynamically

Tags: events, dropzone.js, clickable

I'm using dropzone for single upload. I would like to disable dropzone while uploading. I tried to set `clickable` property to `false` on `addedfile` event and then set it back to `true` on `success`, but dropzone doesn't update with changes. How exactly can I change `clickable` property dynamically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, the dropzone itself has `disable()` and `enable()`. Try the code below

```
init: function() {
    myDropzone = this;
},
addedfile: function() {
    myDropzone.disable()
},
success:function(file, response) {
    myDropzone.enable()
    ....
}
```

Depends on your needs you can replace

```
addedfile: function() {
    myDropzone.disable()
},
```

with the code below

```
sending: function() {
    myDropzone.disable()
},
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. When I disable dropzone (on addedfile or success) it doesn't upload current file. I would like to upload single file and meanwhile prevent adding more files.

Comment: So why don't you use `maxFiles: 1` to your dropzone settings?